# How to echo if field is not found?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm trying to figure out how to echo back if the value entered does not match when a database lookup is done.

I'm using ajax to run the request and php to do the lookup

ajax.js:

```
function showResult(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("description").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?voucher="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

and getuser.php:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["voucher"];
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("test", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM redemption WHERE voucher = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Product</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['product'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['address'] ." ".$row['city'] ." ".$row['province'] ." ".$row['postal'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

What I would like to do is that once the person enters an invalid or a voucher number that is not found I would like to return an error that "Voucher number is not found". There is also a column in the db that stores the status such as "redeemed" or "not redeemed". How could I check for both whether the voucher number exists and if it has already been redeemed?

I assume it'd have to be a syntax such as 
`$sql="SELECT * FROM redemption WHERE voucher = '".$q."'" AND status = 'not redeemed'`
and then use an else or case statement perhaps?

Thanks in advance

Comment: be sure to sanitize your $_GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after the line:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

try:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
    {
    die("Voucher number not found! Please contact us at livingdeal@overstock-king.com");
    }
```

You can probably use the SQL you already have and just do this for the second part:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $row['status']=='redeemed' ? die("voucher already redeemed") : null;
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['product'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['address'] ." ".$row['city'] ." ".$row['province'] ." ".$row['postal'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Note that you are using a MySql extension [that is being softly deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) and that there are JavaScript libraries that [deal with cross browser compatibility issues for you](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and give you a less error prone code base. As Child of the Objective C pointed out, the code is also venerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: this works $row['status']=='redeemed' ? die("voucher already redeemed") : null; but if (empty($result)){die("Voucher number is not found");} doesn't. I'm trying to prevent the form from submitting by using `$voucher = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['voucher']);

$sql= "SELECT * FROM redemption WHERE voucher = '".$voucher."'";

$voucher_check = mysql_query($sql);
if (empty($voucher_check))
 {
  die ("Voucher number is not found, please check your entry");
  }
else {` but it doesn't work. It just keeps going all the way through

Comment: Solved:`$sql= "SELECT * FROM redemption WHERE voucher = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
 {
    die("Voucher number not found! Please contact us at livingdeal@overstock-king.com");
  }`

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out - sorry I missed these comments, had to get off to bed last evening. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The SQL query should fetch the voucher of the known ID.  Use PHP to check the value of the status variable that is returned.  If the query doesn't return anything, the voucher number doesn't exist, otherwise you can tell if it is redeemed or not.

Also, please look into [sanitizing your inputs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).  Your current code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks (one of the most common online hacks).

Answer (score 1):

One thing i recommend to do is for the `status = "not redeemed"` is to use a the `Datatype` to `tinyint` then 
you could just use 1 for redeemed and 0 for not redeemed